# Can ARToolKit load a pattern file dinamically from outside?

Tags: android, design-patterns, runtime, artoolkit

Can ARToolKit load a pattern file (source) dinamically from outside after when i builded from the studio and not added exactly source?

Is there any example for this?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: What is the problem with my question?

Answer (score 0):

Not tried, but seems possible. Try passing the absolute path of `.patt` file in the config for the `addTrackable()` method.

```
String config = "single;" + pattFileAbsolutePath + trackableWidth;
trackableUIDs[i] = getInstance().addTrackable(config);
```

It's worth giving a try.